# Django conditional annotation with join on DateTimeField

Tags: sql, django

Is it possible to annotate queryset with conditional data from another table.
For example I have following tables:

```
class User(Model):
    name = CharField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Event(Model):
    name = CharField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    condition = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to annotate every Event with amount of users which created field is greater than event created field. Then I want to select only those events for which annotation value is greater than Event.condition.
It seems really easy in raw SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), event.id FROM event 
JOIN user ON user.created > event.created
GROUP BY event.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > event.condition;
```

Though not sure if it's possible to create using django ORM without extra() function.